# How to make date selection to available 3 days back from today?

Tags: php, html, date

I am having a difficulty in making the date selection to be available for at least the past 3 days. Now my system is currently working fine but only able to select today date as the latest date.  I want it to be available for past 3 days. Lets say if it is 25 today and I want it to be available minimum 22 or whatever.

Here is my codes for the input part. I hope someone can help me. Thanks a lot. :D

```
 <!-- Date -->
                        <div class="box-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Date: *</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <?php 

                           $today = date("Y-m-d");

                        ?>

                <input type="date" id="myDate" name="date" min="<?php echo $today;?>" selected value="<?php echo $today;?>" required=required/>

                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div><!-- /.box-body -->
```

Answer (score 1):

example:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Etc/GMT");//your timezone

function get_past_N_days($n){
    $res = array();
    for($i = 0; $i<=$n ; $i++){
        $res[] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-{$i} day"));        
    }    
    return $res;
}

var_export(get_past_N_days(3));

##############################
array (
    0 => '2015-11-25',
    1 => '2015-11-24',
    2 => '2015-11-23',
    3 => '2015-11-22',
)
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer. But I am not very clear where to apply since I just started using php a while ago.

Answer (score 1):

I put another variable called `$ystd` and here is the codes that work for me.

```
$ystd = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date .' -3 day'));
```